# copy file to remote linux machine from windows using java without FTP protocol

Tags: java, linux, windows, io

Is there any way to copy file to remote linux machine from windows using java without FTP protocol?

Comment: There are more than one way to achieve this. You can use Sockets, RMI etc to transfer file from windows to linux or linux to windows

Comment: you could do scp, using JSch http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/

Answer (score -1):

**Transfer file using java socket**

Server/Sender

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sender {
    public static Scanner scanner;
    /**
     * 
     * @param args
     * this function collect all required data from user.
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        String fileLocation;
        int portNo;
        scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter port number of machine(e.g. '2000') :");
        portNo=scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter file location with file name (e.g. 'D:\\abc.txt'): ");
        fileLocation=scanner.next();
         Sender.send(portNo,fileLocation);
    }
    /**
     * this function actually transfers file
     * @param portNo
     * @param fileLocation
     * @return
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public static  void send(int portNo,String fileLocation) throws IOException
    {

        FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
        BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = null;

        OutputStream outputStream = null;
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        Socket socket = null;

        //creating connection between sender and receiver
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNo);
            System.out.println("Waiting for receiver...");
                try {
                        socket = serverSocket.accept();
                        System.out.println("Accepted connection : " + socket);
                        //connection established successfully

                        //creating object to send file
                        File file = new File (fileLocation);
                        byte [] byteArray  = new byte [(int)file.length()];
                        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
                        bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(fileInputStream);
                        bufferedInputStream.read(byteArray,0,byteArray.length); // copied file into byteArray

                        //sending file through socket
                        outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
                        System.out.println("Sending " + fileLocation + "( size: " + byteArray.length + " bytes)");
                        outputStream.write(byteArray,0,byteArray.length);           //copying byteArray to socket
                        outputStream.flush();                                       //flushing socket
                        System.out.println("Done.");                                //file has been sent
                    }
                    finally {
                        if (bufferedInputStream != null) bufferedInputStream.close();
                        if (outputStream != null) bufferedInputStream.close();
                        if (socket!=null) socket.close();
                    }       
            } catch (IOException e) {

                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                if (serverSocket != null) serverSocket.close();
            }
    }
}
```

Client/Receiver

```
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Receiver {


    public static Scanner scanner;


    public static void main (String [] args ) throws IOException {


        String fileLocation,ipAddress;
        int portNo;
        scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter ipAddress of machine(if you are testing this on same machine than enter 127.0.0.1) :");
        ipAddress=scanner.next();

        System.out.println("Enter port number of machine(e.g. '2000') :");
        portNo=scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter file location with file name to save (e.g. 'D:\\abc.txt'): ");     //you can modify this program to receive file name from server and then you can skip this step
        fileLocation=scanner.next();
        Receiver.receiveFile(ipAddress, portNo, fileLocation);


    }
    public static void receiveFile(String ipAddress,int portNo,String fileLocation) throws IOException
    {

        int bytesRead=0;
        int current = 0;
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
        BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = null;
        Socket socket = null;
        try {

            //creating connection.
            socket = new Socket(ipAddress,portNo);
            System.out.println("connected.");

            // receive file
            byte [] byteArray  = new byte [6022386];                    //I have hard coded size of byteArray, you can send file size from socket before creating this.
            System.out.println("Please wait downloading file");

            //reading file from socket
            InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
            fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileLocation);
            bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
            bytesRead = inputStream.read(byteArray,0,byteArray.length);                 //copying file from socket to byteArray

            current = bytesRead;
            do {
                bytesRead =inputStream.read(byteArray, current, (byteArray.length-current));
                if(bytesRead >= 0) current += bytesRead;
            } while(bytesRead > -1);
            bufferedOutputStream.write(byteArray, 0 , current);                         //writing byteArray to file
            bufferedOutputStream.flush();                                               //flushing buffers

            System.out.println("File " + fileLocation  + " downloaded ( size: " + current + " bytes read)");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            if (fileOutputStream != null) fileOutputStream.close();
            if (bufferedOutputStream != null) bufferedOutputStream.close();
            if (socket != null) socket.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code does not work. The client ignores end of stream, so it never stops reading from the connection. It also assumes that the entire file fits into memory, and hat its size fits into an `int`.